# Difference between array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester')) and array('Acl' => 'requester') in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model, acl, behavior

I'm following the ACL tutorial for CakePHP 1.3 and I was wondering if there is a functional difference between declaring a behavior like this:

```
var $actsAs = array('Acl' => 'requester');
```

and like this:

```
var $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no difference. You can even declare [this](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1) way:

```
var $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('requester'));
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for clarifying and for the link also.

Answer (score 0):

Though your two examples are both valid and correct for CakePHP 1.3.4 ([`cake/libs/model/behaviors/acl.php` lines 48-51](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/acl-behavior/#line-47)), the suggested third method posted by bancer is not correct. Because the AclBehavior defaults to 'requester' when it cannot find the configuration, this is a potentially frustrating bug in that it will work as expected until you attempt to change the type to 'controlled'. (it also doesn't work in [CakePHP 1.2](http://api12.cakephp.org/view_source/acl-behavior/#line-49) - Mark Story made a change to that line at the [advice of an anonymous user](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1#comment-61).) If you do want to replace your third example, `var $actsAs = array('Acl');` should do fine (unless you want `type` to be `'controlled'`, but you can then see to add the option).

Comment: The third method was not the suggestion. It was an illustration of use. You can find more references to that if you google "array('Acl' => array('requester'))" http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%22array%28%27Acl%27+%3D%3E+array%28%27requester%27%29%29%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=fad0bccbc44b8016. It is strange that Mark made that mistake.